# Installshield causing error on Silent Install

Tags: vbscript, installshield

The installer im currently building runs perfectly fine on a normal install (with UI) however, when trying to run the installer in silent mode i get the following error:

> Error 1720. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. Custom action GetIniFile script error -2147467259, Msi API Error: TargetPath,Folder Line 34, Column 6

the VBScript on that line is:

```
Session.TargetPath("INISYBASEDIR")  = value
Session.TargetPath("INSTALLDIR")  = value
```

Command Line to trigger silent install:

```
setup.exe /s /V"/qn"
```

The GetIniFile script is set to run after `CostInitialize` exec sequence.

What am I doing wrong? As mentioned above, it works fine when running the installer with the UI.

Comment: Is that the error from the message box or the verbose log? (I don't use VBScript enough to remember; sometimes the verbose log tells more.) Is `value` a sane value? Just triple-checking, do you have directories named INISYBASEDIR and INSTALLDIR?

Comment: the error is in the event log, and the above script just sets the directory value based on the registry entry, like i said above, it does work in the UI, so not sure why its not here